# C++ - valgrind - Mismatched free() / delete / delete []

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

In my program I use global variable `alloc_ptr first_alloc = NULL;` and following struct and functions for memory management:

```
typedef struct alloc_struct
{
    void* ptr;
    struct alloc_struct* prev;
} *alloc_ptr;

void *alloc(unsigned long size)
{
    alloc_ptr tmp = new struct alloc_struct;
    tmp->ptr = new char[size];
    tmp->prev = first_alloc;
    first_alloc = tmp;
    return tmp->ptr;
}

void free_one(void* ptr)
{
    alloc_ptr tmp = first_alloc;
    alloc_ptr tmp2 = tmp;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr == tmp->ptr)
        {
            delete[] tmp->ptr;
            if(tmp == first_alloc)
            {
                first_alloc = tmp->prev;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp2->prev = tmp->prev;
            }
            delete tmp;
            break;
        }
        tmp2 = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->prev;
    }
}

void free_all()
{
    alloc_ptr tmp;
    while (first_alloc != NULL)
    {
        delete[] first_alloc->ptr;
        tmp = first_alloc->prev;
        delete first_alloc;
        first_alloc = tmp;
    }
    first_alloc = NULL;
}
```

I tried my program with valgrind and received lots of errors `Mismatched free() / delete / delete []` in functions `free_one` and `free_all`. If I change `delete` and `delete[]` it has no effect. What is the problem here?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and std::`shared_ptr`

Comment: Also using void pointers is a very bad mistake. A void void pointers. They are bad news and smacks of a bad design

Comment: As you can see, I use delete for new and delete[] for new ... []. So I don't see problem here.

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: I copy bytes. Char allocation is there only for char size equal to 1 byte. I also use memcpy.

Comment: Do yourself a favour. Dump void pointers. Look up `std::string`, `std::vector` and `srd;;shared-ptr`

Comment: My advice is that you throw away this code because it looks unfixable.

Comment: *"I use delete for new and delete[] for new ... []. So I don't see problem here"*. But there is - you must have the same types in `new[]` and `delete[]`. From the standard: *"In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @juanchopanza: sure. Declaring ptr as char * is impossible.

Comment: @EdHeal: this example seems to use a singly linked list, not a vector. Furthermore, shared_ptr has its overhead, and looking at this sample, there is absolutely no need of using it.

Answer (score 3):

Trying with g++ 6.3.0, the compiler generates the following
calls for the two lines allocating/freeing ptr:

```
tmp->ptr = new char[size];
=> _Znam which is operator new[](unsigned long)/__builtin_vec_new

delete[] tmp->ptr;
=> _ZdlPv which is operator delete(void*)/__builtin_delete
```

So, Valgrind complains seems correct.

g++ also gives warnings such as :

```
warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined [-Wdelete-incomplete]
             delete[] tmp->ptr;
```

So, your code is undefined behaviour, the compiler can do whatever, and
has decided to generate something that triggers a valgrind error.